# Best C# representation of this JSON object?

Tags: c#, json

I'm looking for advice on the best way to represent this JSON object in C#.

To be clear, I'm not trying to convert from an existing JSON string to C# object - this is from scratch. I can visualize what I'm trying to create as JSON, but not sure how that translates...

```
[
{
   "EquipmentID": "ASD2F",
   "ConnectionIDs":[
      { "ConnectionID": "HD4GH" },
      { "ConnectionID": "KAFD3" },
      { "ConnectionID": "NA3AF" }
   ]
},
{
   "EquipmentID": "GAE31",
   "ConnectionIDs":[
      { "ConnectionID": "HJA03" },
      { "ConnectionID": "FGVA1" },
      { "ConnectionID": "GHAD8" }
   ]
}
]
```

That's basically an array of EquipmentID's, each EquipmentID containing an array of ConnectionID's. I've been tinkering with a few different Classes containing arrays, lists, etc... but I can't seem to settle on anything. I know this should be incredibly simple, so thanks in advance for helping out!

Comment: the ConnectionIDs array should just be [ "HJA03", "FGVA1", "GHAD8" ], take out the "ConnectionID" stuff

Comment: Allen, if I were doing something with that string as a JSON object, then yes, you'd be correct. However, that's not the point... like I said above, I'm not trying to do anything with that string. That string just came out of my head. It's just an idea of what I'm trying to create in C#.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this makes sense:

```
class Equipment {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public List<string> ConnectionIds { get; set; }
}
```

Then you'd have a variable of type `List<Equipment>` to hold the equipments.

By the way, it's not clear to me whether `ConnectionIds` themselves are equipments or not. If they are, you'd basically have:

```
class Equipment {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public List<Equipment> Connections { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: ConnectionIds are not equipment, but rather properties of the equipment. This is a rough example of how our datacenter handles equipments in our asset database. Each "equipment" (think server) has multiple connections (i.e., power, network, kvm, etc).

Anyway, I think this should work out just right... I think where I was getting confused was in how to consume the class. It didn't occur to me to use the class as a list type.

I'll give it a shot tomorrow when I get to the office. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
class Equipment {
    string id;
    string[] connectionIds;
}
```